# Mongoose: How to populate across multiple levels and use field selection in the same time?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, orm

I have succesfully used population [across multiple levels](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html#deep-populate) and [field selection](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html#field-selection) separately. But I couldn't find a way to do them both at the same time.
Population across multiple levels

```
 Profile.findOne({ user: req.user.id })
  .populate({
        path: "user",
        populate: { path: "following" },
      })
```

Field selection:

```
 Profile.findOne({ user: req.user.id })
       .populate("user", ["name", "avatar"])
```

I want to do something like this:
**NOTE: THIS DOESN'T WORK**

```
 Profile.findOne({ user: req.user.id })
      .populate({
            path: ["user", ["name", "avatar"]],
            populate: { path: "following" },
```

---

This is the `Profile` model:

```
const ProfileSchema = new Schema({
  //We want to associate the user with the profile
  user: {
    //This will associate the user by his id
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "users",
  },
  // We want a user friendly url
  handle: {
    type: String,
    // required: true, // Even though we are doing pre-validatioon
    max: 40,
  },
  bio: {
    type: String,
  },
  school: {
    type: String,
  },
  major: {
    type: String,
  },
  website: {
    type: String,
  },
  location: {
    type: String,
  },
  // Optional (might add it later)
  /**
   *   status: {
    //where they are in their career
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
   */
  skills: {
    // In the form they will put skill1,skill2,.. and we will turn that into an array
    type: [String],
    // required: true,
  },
  interests: {
    // In the form they will put interest1,interest2,.. and we will turn that into an array
    type: [String],
    // required: true,
  },
  help_offers: {
    // In the form they will put help_offer1,help_offer2,.. and we will turn that into an array
    type: [String],
    // required: true,
  },
  // Might be volunteering experience
  experience: [
    {
      title: { type: String, required: true },
      company: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
      },
      location: {
        type: String,
      },
      from: {
        type: Date,
        required: true,
      },
      to: {
        type: Date,
        // Not required, going to be a checkbox
      },
      current: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: false,
      },
      description: {
        type: String,
      },
    },
  ],
  education: [
    {
      school: { type: String, required: true },
      degree: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
      },
      fieldofstudy: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
      },
      from: {
        type: Date,
        required: true,
      },
      to: {
        type: Date,
        // Not required, going to be a checkbox
      },
      current: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: false,
      },
      description: {
        type: String,
      },
    },
  ],
  social: {
    youtube: {
      type: String,
    },
    twitter: {
      type: String,
    },
    facebook: {
      type: String,
    },
    linkedin: {
      type: String,
    },
    instagram: {
      type: String,
    },
  },
  date: {
    type: Date,
    dafault: Date.now,
  },
  videoURL: {
    type: String,
  },
});
```

This is the `User` model:

```
const UserSchema = new Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  surname: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
 avatar: {
    type: String,
  },
  birthday: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  country: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  date: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now,
  },
  following: [
    {
      type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      //The User has only ObjectId in uses array. ref helps us get full fields of User when we call populate() method.
      //https://bezkoder.com/mongodb-many-to-many-mongoose/
      ref: "users",
    },
  ],
  followers: [
    {
      type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "users",
    },
  ],
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`I am not sure if I understood your aim by this`

```js
Profile.findOne({ user: req.user.id })
    .populate({
        path: ["user", ["name", "avatar"]],
        populate: { path: "following" },
```

But if what i understood is what you want, then we're lucky. here is what i got.

```js
await RequestAproves.find()
         .populate('user', 'firstName surname email roleId')
         .populate({
              path: 'request',
              populate: [
                     { path: 'budgetItem', select: 'code name' },
                     { path: 'user', select: 'firstName surname' },
                   ],
             }
       )
```

`More details will come later, Sorry, I couldnt use your schema description, Incase it doesnt work out, let me know, ill try to use your schema.`